# Output to pipe and file at the same time even if pipe isn't accepting inputs

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, cygwin

So, I made a script for Cygwin that uses Windows's ImageMagick and FFmpeg, but I am not sure if the results here will also apply for bash on Linux. So, what the script does is I have some cartoon video files and I'm using Waifu2x to enhance and upscale the images to 4K, and then using ImageMagick to pipe it to FFmpeg, which is also used to resize it to 3840x2160 in case the resolution is slightly different. Here's a small script I wrote for this example to simplify how it outputs to FFmpeg, as the real script is extremely lengthy and complex.

```
#!/bin/bash
fun(){
convert out.png JPG:-|tee "$outfile"
}
fun|ffmpeg -f image2pipe -r 60 -i - -c:v libx265 -movflags +faststart "$outputfile"
```

Now, what I noticed is that if FFmpeg fails to encode, the function continues but fails to output to `$outfile`. What I want to do is have it able to output to that file in case the encoding fails since I also write all the images to a cache folder for FFmpeg to run through in case the encoding fails, but I also want to write to both the pipe for FFmpeg and the file at the same time. What seems to be happening is that the command `tee` appears to be refusing to write to the file if it can't write to the pipe. I'm not sure if this behavior is intended, and/or if it also does this on Linux bash. How can I get around this and have it write to the file even if it can't write to the pipe, but write to both at the same time rather than writing to the file and attempting to read it back to the pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `tee` with the `-p` option? It makes `tee` continue writing even if `tee` can't write to its standard output, which in your case means it should cope if `ffmpeg` fails.

```
fun() {
        convert out.png JPG:- | tee -p "$outfile"
}
```